# Pass row_id from one Activity to another so I can delete row from activity based on row_id

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am attempting to delete a record from my database,

### Short Summary:

1. My database populates a listview
2. The user can click the listview and
   view more details on a new activity
3. I want to able to delete the
   record from this new activity

### CODE

I have a class named `ModuleDatabaseHandler` that manages the database. In this, I have a method called `getData()` that populates records to a `ListView` in `ActivityViewAll`:

### ModuleDatabaseHandler

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE,
            KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL,
            KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL_SHORT, KEY_LECTURE_DAY,
            KEY_LECTURE_DAY_SHORT, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_END_TIME,
            KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    int indexModCode = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MODULE_CODE);

    int indexLectPracShort = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL_SHORT);

    int indexLectDayShort = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_DAY_SHORT);
    int indexLectStart = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_START_TIME);

    int indexLectLoc = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(c.getString(indexModCode) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectPracShort) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectDayShort) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectStart) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectLoc));
    }



return results;
    }
```

This data is read in by `ActivityViewAll`:

### ActivityViewAll

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_modules_test);

    ModuleDatabaseHandler info = new ModuleDatabaseHandler(this);
    info.open();
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
    info.close();

    l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

I have another method in the `ModuleDatabaseHandler` class called `getAllData()` that allows the user to press a `ListView` item and read full details about the item on a new activity, `ActivityFullDetails`:

```
    public String getAllData(int specified_position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int position = specified_position;

        if(c.moveToPosition(specified_position)) {
            String result = "";
            for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex<c.getColumnCount();columnIndex++) {
                result += c.getString(columnIndex)+" ";
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Row " + specified_position + " does not exist");
        }

}
```

The data is transfered from the listView in `ActivityViewAll` to `ActivityFullDetails` using `onItemClick`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    TextView temp = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    ModuleDatabaseHandler info = new ModuleDatabaseHandler(this);
    info.open();
    String module_info = info.getAllData(i);
    info.close();

    Intent fullModuleDetails = new Intent();
    fullModuleDetails.setClassName("com.example.collegetimetable",
            "com.example.collegetimetable.ModuleDetails");

    fullModuleDetails.putExtra("list1", module_info);

    startActivity(fullModuleDetails);

}
```

Back in the `ModuleDatabaseHandler` class, I created a method called `deleteEntry` to attempt to delete a row:

```
public void deleteEntry(long row){
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_MODULES,  KEY_ROWID + "=" + row, null);

}
```

### The Problem

How can I pass the `ROW_ID` from the `ModuleDatabaseHandler` class to the listView in `ActivityViewAll` and then to the `ActivityFullDetails` so I can delete the record?

### SOLVED

Thanks to `Serge` who helped me solve this, by creating a `getRowId` method as seen in the accepted answer. Although I did have to add a cursor query within the method which is not shown in the accepted answer i.e.:

```
    public int getRowID(int specified_position) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL, KEY_LECTURE_DAY, KEY_START_TIME,KEY_END_TIME, KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
// rest of method as shown below
}
```

This method is called in the `ActivityViewAll` activity page from an instance of `ModuleDatabaseHandler` class, passed to the `ActivityFullDetails` page using `putExtra`,(and received using `getIntent().getExtras` as usual)..the delete method can then use the `rowid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add function

```
public int getRowID(int specified_position) {
    int position = specified_position;
    if(c.moveToPosition(specified_position)) {
        return c.getInteger(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Row " + specified_position + " does not exist");
    }

}
```

And then to get it use

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

TextView temp = (TextView) view;
Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();

ModuleDatabaseHandler info = new ModuleDatabaseHandler(this);
info.open();
String module_info = info.getAllData(i);
int rowID = info.getRowID(i);
info.close();

Intent fullModuleDetails = new Intent();
fullModuleDetails.setClassName("com.example.collegetimetable",
        "com.example.collegetimetable.ModuleDetails");

fullModuleDetails.putExtra("list1", module_info);
fullModuleDetails.putExtra("rowid", rowID);

startActivity(fullModuleDetails);

}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I do not want to display the Row Id on the activity - thanks anyhow.

Comment: Let me change the answer

Comment: I changed getRowID function. What exactly did not work? was getRowID function working? Were you able to retrieve "rowid" extra?

Comment: Hey, it is working now - thanks, I had to add the information within the `Rowid` function i.e. `String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL, KEY_LECTURE_DAY, KEY_START_TIME,KEY_END_TIME, KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO};Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null, null, null, null);` Initially I forget to add the `KEY_ROWID` and it wouldn`t work. Thanks for your help